# How to rotate 2D objects such that a pair of normal vectors are opposite

Tags: matrices, geometry

Given two 2D shapes where each side has a normal vector, how can you rotate one of those objects such a pair of the objects normal vectors are opposite?

Example:

[image]

To

[image]

Assume that angles below X are negative and above are positive. 0 degrees is the positive X axis, and 180/-180 is the negative X axis.

Comment: One vector is not sufficient. If you think of the shared vector as an axis, the objects can rotate around it. On the mating face, both objects should have two orthogonal vectors. Then, it is very easy to construct a rotation matrix for one of them, which rotates the object so that one pair of vectors is perpendicular, and the other pair parallel. So, each of the normal vectors should be paired with a "this way" vector; when mating, the two "this way" vectors will be parallel, and the normals opposite each other.

Comment: Can't a parallel vector be derived from the normal vector by adding or subtracting 90 degrees?

Comment: No. Think about how a shuttle docks with a space station. One vector is perpendicular to the face of the docking hatch, and that is your normal vector. However, the hatches only work in one orientation. You can't derive that orientation from the normal vector, because the hatch is round. You need to know one additional direction, "this way", to match the orientation of the hatch. So, to derive the rotation you need to mate two faces, each of the two faces needs two orthogonal (perpendicular) vectors: a normal vector, and an orientation vector ("this way").

Comment: Note that if you don't care about the orientation -- in the illustration in the question, the two shapes are clearly oriented the same way, but let's say you don't care if the other had the end pointing left point towards us instead, as long as the shared faces mate properly --, you can just pick any two random vectors that are perpendicular to their respective face normals. (You can even start with any vector that is not parallel to the face normal, and just orthonormalize it.)

Comment: What do you mean by a pair of normal vectors being opposite?  Does that mean overlapping as they appear to do in the second image?  Technically the first image also satisfies that with those two vectors that "point towards each other" in the middle.  Vectors only tell us two things: magnitude and direction.  Their locations aren't really relevant.

Comment: In the first image 2 vectors are opposite and that is what I want. Setting position afterwards is easy and outside of what I'm asking. I'm trying to find the algorithm for rotating these objects such that I can set any 2 given vectors opposite each other. @Nominal Animal I don't really follow. Could you write out an answer explicitly stating what additional vectors are required and how the algorithm might work?

Comment: @JamesLowrey: Done.

Comment: @tilper: Normal vector $\vec{a}$ and normal vector $\vec{b}$ are opposite, if and only if $\vec{a} = -\vec{b}$ (or equivalently, $-\vec{a} = \vec{b}$). I assume JamesLowrey is talking about a pure rotation here, and the illustration only combines that with a translation to convey the intent.

Comment: @JamesLowrey: If you intend to do this progressively, as in for example an animation where the rotation occurs smoothly, the versor (unit quaternion) approach is very similar. (Versors are easy to interpolate, and each interpolated versor is converted to a matrix.) In that case, each object has their orientation versor, plus a versor for each possible "mating" face. (Thus, we actually get four versors, not two.) The versor describing the overall rotation is constructed in exactly the same way, except using quaternion multiplication rather than matrix multiplication.

Comment: For anyone wondering, note that when I wrote the above comments and my earlier answer, I had read 2D as 3D.  I do not know how it happened, but it did. I apologize for the confusion it caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NominalAnimal's response was helpful to brush up on the theory. But the solution to my problem ended up much simpler. One object's normal vector needs to be rotated to another object's vector. Here is some pseudo code to do this

```
var start = my_joint.normal         #2D vector normal to the object's side
var end = - their_joint.normal.rotated(their_joint.get_global_rot())
var ang = start.angle_to(end)
set_global_rot(ang)
```

Just calculate the angle between the normal vectors, but be sure to incorporate the global rotation of the stationary vector. Then set the object's rotation to that angle.

Answer (score 1):

**If** this were a 3D problem, and not a 2D one:

As I mentioned in a comment, you really need two orthogonal vectors per object to rotate one to match the other. As an example, consider the following image:
[image: Two boxes with two unit vectors each]

The left cube has orthonormal unit vectors $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$. The transparent arrow indicates the third orthonormal unit vector, $\hat{k}$, that we can derive from the other two. As a reminder:
$$\begin{array}{r|r}
\hat{i} \cdot \hat{i} = 1 & \hat{i} \times \hat{j} = \hat{k} \\
\hat{j} \cdot \hat{j} = 1 & \hat{j} \times \hat{k} = \hat{i} \\
\hat{k} \cdot \hat{k} = 1 & \hat{k} \times \hat{i} = \hat{j} \\
\hline
\hat{i} \cdot \hat{j} = 0 &
\hat{i} \cdot \hat{k} = 0 \\
\hat{j} \cdot \hat{i} = 0 &
\hat{j} \cdot \hat{k} = 0 \\
\hat{k} \cdot \hat{i} = 0 &
\hat{k} \cdot \hat{j} = 0
\end{array}$$
Similarly for the cube on the right, for $\hat{u}$, $\hat{v}$, and the transparent unnamed $\hat{w}$. To reiterate,
$$\hat{k} = \hat{i} \times \hat{j} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \hat{w} = \hat{u} \times \hat{v} \tag{0}\label{0}$$
where $\times$ denotes [vector cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Coordinate_notation).

(In the illustration, $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ are unit normals for their respective faces, and $\hat{j}$, $\hat{k}$, $\hat{v}$, and $\hat{w}$ are parallel to the respective faces.)

For vectors and their components, I shall use notation
$$\hat{u} = \left [ \begin{array}{c} u_x \\ u_y \\ u_z \end{array} \right ] = ( u_x ,\, u_y ,\, u_z )$$
where the subscript names the component; similarly for $\hat{v}$, $\hat{w}$, $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$, and $\hat{k}$.

To construct rotation matrices using the above, we also need to remember three key properties of pure rotation matrices.

1. Pure rotation matrices' column vectors correspond to the coordinate axis vectors after the rotation. If we label the elements in a pure rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$,
   $$\mathbf{R} = \left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
   x_x & y_x & z_x \\ x_y & y_y & z_y \\ x_z & y_z & z_z \end{array} \right ]  \tag{1}\label{1}$$
   then $\hat{x} = ( x_x ,\, x_y ,\, x_z )$, $\hat{y} = ( y_x ,\, y_y ,\, y_z )$, and $\hat{z} = ( z_x ,\, z_y ,\, z_z )$ correspond to the axis vectors $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ after the rotation by $\mathbf{R}$, because
   $$\left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
   x_x & y_x & z_x \\ x_y & y_y & z_y \\ x_z & y_z & z_z \end{array} \right ] \left [ \begin{array}{c}
   1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right ] = \left [ \begin{array}{c}
   x_x \\ x_y \\ x_z \end{array} \right ]$$and similarly for the other two unit axis vectors.
2. Because pure rotation matrices are [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), their inverse is their transpose:
   $$\mathbf{R}^{-1} = \mathbf{R}^{T} = \left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
   x_x & x_y & x_z \\ y_x & y_y & y_z \\ z_x & z_y & z_z \end{array} \right ] \tag{2}\label{2}$$
3. If our vectors are column vectors like I use here, we multiply the rotation matrix and the vector in that order (sometimes called *right multiply* or *post-multiply*), and we can combine several rotations by multiplying them. Because matrix multiplication is not commutative, the order is important: first rotation is always rightmost, last rotation leftmost:
   $$\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{R}_2 \mathbf{R}_1 \tag{3}\label{3}$$

The logic to constructing the rotation is very simple: we find the matrix that rotates the cube so that the unit normal vectors match coordinate axes; then we find the matrix that rotates the coordinate axis vectors to match the second cube; then we combine the two rotations to get the desired rotation.

The small wrinkle here is that we do not want the two pairs (triplets) of vectors to match; we actually want
$$\begin{array}{r} -\hat{i} \to \hat{u} \\ \hat{j} \to \hat{v} \end{array}$$
and therefore also that $$-\hat{k} = -\hat{i} \times \hat{j} \to \hat{w} = \hat{u} \times \hat{v}$$

If we apply $\eqref{0}$, $\eqref{1}$, and $\eqref{2}$ to the unit vectors (after noting the abovementioned wrinkle) in the cube on the left, the first rotation matrix is
$$\mathbf{R}_1 = \left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
-i_x & -i_y & -i_z \\ j_x & j_y & j_z \\
i_z j_y - i_y j_z & i_x j_z - i_z j_x & i_y j_x - i_x j_y \end{array} \right ]$$
and if we apply $\eqref{0}$ and $\eqref{1}$ to the unit vectors on the cube on the right, the second rotation matrix is
$$\mathbf{R}_2 = \left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
u_x & v_x & u_y v_z - u_z v_y \\
u_y & v_y & u_z v_x - u_x v_z \\
u_z & v_z & u_x v_y - u_y v_x \end{array} \right ]$$
Applying $\eqref{3}$, we get the combined matrix that rotates the cube on the left so that $\hat{i} = -\hat{u}$ and $\hat{j} = \hat{v}$:
$$\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{R}_2 \mathbf{R}_1$$
Note that when implementing this in a computer program, it is a good idea to calculate the components in the first two matrices (in temporary variables or arrays) first, and then just apply [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Square_matrices) to obtain the final rotation matrix. This leads to a function with 39 multiplications, 18 additions, 6 subtractions, and three negations, and a total of 18 temporary variables (and thus 27 assignments). It is surprisingly few operations, and should not be a bottleneck in any case. (If profiling indicates it nevertheless is — in some special-weird case —, you can shave off 12 multiplications and six subtractions by explicitly precalculating and storing the third unit vectors $\hat{k}$ and $\hat{w}$, too.)

Comment: Wow high quality comment! Unfortunately I'm not following everything you say and how it relates to my 2D scenario. Def appreciate the help tho. I just need to sit and think about it for awhile, and will update when it clicks for me.

Comment: @JamesLowrey: Awww crap. I'm an absolute idiot. I somehow read that 2D as 3D! Of course the 2D case is simpler, can can be implemented with just one vector. My sheer stupidity.... :(

Comment: Haha it happens to the best of us. I'm the one who can't figure out 2D uk. Really appreciate the effort in this 3D response tho

Comment: @JamesLowrey: I'll add the 2D case in a separate answer; it's quite straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

In 2D, a single normal vector does indeed suffice. (My other answer deals with the 3D case.)

Let's say the object to be rotated has an unit vector $$\hat{n} = \left [ \begin{array}{c} n_x \\
n_y \end{array} \right ] = ( n_x ,\, n_y )$$and that the target object has an unit vector $$\hat{u} = \left [ \begin{array}{c} u_x \\
u_y \end{array} \right ] = ( u_x ,\, u_y )$$

We can form a 2D basis, i.e. obtain the other vector perpendicular to the named vector, by rotating the unit vector 90° counterclockwise:
$$\hat{m} = \left [ \begin{array}{c} -n_y \\
n_x \end{array} \right ] = ( -n_y ,\, n_x ) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \hat{v} = \left [ \begin{array}{c} -u_y \\
u_x \end{array} \right ] = ( -u_y ,\, u_x ) \tag{0}\label{10}$$

Note that $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{u}$ are unit vectors, i.e.
$$\left\lVert\hat{n}\right\rVert = 1 \qquad \text{or} \qquad \hat{n} \cdot \hat{n} = 1^2 = 1$$
and
$$\left\lVert\hat{u}\right\rVert = 1 \qquad \text{or} \qquad \hat{u} \cdot \hat{u} = 1^2 = 1$$
The rotated vectors are then also unit vectors.

To construct rotations using such basis vectors, we need to apply three features of pure rotation matrices,

1. The column vectors of the matrix describes how the matrix rotates the unit axis vectors ($x$-axis $(1,0)$ and $y$-axis $(0,1)$).

   In other words, if we label the components of a pure 2D rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$
   $$\mathbf{R} = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} a_x & b_x \\
   a_y & b_y \end{array} \right ] \tag{1}\label{11}$$
   then $$\mathbf{R} \left [ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\
   0 \end{array} \right ] = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} a_x & b_x \\
   a_y & b_y \end{array} \right ] \left [ \begin{array}{c} 1 \\
   0 \end{array} \right ] = \left [ \begin{array}{c} a_x \\
   a_y \end{array} \right ]$$
   and $$\mathbf{R} \left [ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\
   1 \end{array} \right ] = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} a_x & b_x \\
   a_y & b_y \end{array} \right ] \left [ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\
   1 \end{array} \right ]  = \left [ \begin{array}{c} b_x \\
   b_y \end{array} \right ]$$
2. Because a pure rotation matrix is [orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), its transpose is its inverse,
   $$\mathbf{R}^{-1} = \mathbf{R}^{T} \tag{2}\label{12}$$

   In other words, if we wish to reverse a rotation described by some matrix $\mathbf{M}$, we simply apply the rotation described by the transpose of that matrix, $\mathbf{M}^{T}$.

   Combining this and the previous points $\eqref{10}$ and $\eqref{11}$, if we have an unit vector, say $\hat{c} = ( c_x ,\, c_y )$, pure rotation matrix
   $$\mathbf{R}_x = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} c_x & c_y \\ -c_y & c_x \end{array} \right ]$$
   rotates $\hat{c}$ to $(1 , 0)$, i.e. to positive $x$ axis. Similarly, pure rotation matrix
   $$\mathbf{R}_y = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} -c_y & c_x \\ c_x & c_y \end{array} \right ]$$
   rotates $\hat{c}$ to $(0 , 1)$, i.e. to positive $y$ axis.
3. Rotation matrices can be combined by multiplying them together. Because their order does not commute, the order matters. Using the notation shown here, the first rotation matrix is the rightmost, and the last rotation leftmost, i.e.
   $$\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{R}_2 \mathbf{R}_1 \tag{3}\label{13}$$

Logically, we construct the desired rotation matrix in two sub-rotations: first, we rotate so that the desired vectors match the axis unit vectors; then we rotate so that the axis unit vectors match the desired final vectors.

In OP's case, the desired rotation is such that $\mathbf{R} \hat{n} = -\hat{u}$, or equivalently, $\mathbf{R} (-\hat{n}) = \hat{u}$.

So, applying that, $\eqref{10}$, $\eqref{11}$ and $\eqref{12}$, we get
$$\mathbf{R}_1 = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} -n_x & -n_y \\
n_y & n_x \end{array} \right ]$$
which rotates $-\hat{n}$ to the $x$ axis ($(1,0)$).

Applying $\eqref{10}$ and $\eqref{11}$, we get
$$\mathbf{R}_2 = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} u_x & -u_y \\
u_y & u_x \end{array} \right ]$$
which rotates the $x$ axis ($(1,0)$) to $\hat{u}$.

Applying $\eqref{13}$ to combine $\mathbf{R}_1$ and $\mathbf{R}_2$, in that order, we get
$$\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{R}_2 \mathbf{R}_1 = \left [ \begin{array}{cc} u_x & -u_y \\
u_y & u_x \end{array} \right ] \left [ \begin{array}{cc} -n_x & -n_y \\
n_y & n_x \end{array} \right ] = \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
-u_x n_x - u_y n_y &
-u_x n_y - u_y n_x \\
-u_y n_x + u_x n_y &
 -u_y n_y + u_x n_x \end{array} \right ]$$

The combined matrix $\mathbf{R}$ rotates $-\hat{n}$ to $\hat{u}$, i.e. $\mathbf{R}(-\hat{n}) = -\mathbf{R}\hat{n} = \hat{u}$.

When implemented in a computer program, it makes sense to calculate the four products ($u_x n_x$, $u_x n_y$, $u_y n_x$, and $u_y n_y$) into temporary variables first. The entire operation then takes just four multiplications, two additions, two subtractions, and two negations (as well as six assignments) -- an extremely quick and lightweight operation.

Do note that the math shown here does assume that the normal vectors $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{u}$ are unit vectors. If they are not, you need to normalize them first, using
$$\begin{cases} n_x' = \frac{n_x}{\sqrt{n_x^2 + n_y^2}} \\
n_y' = \frac{n_y}{\sqrt{n_x^2 + n_y^2}} \end{cases} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
\begin{cases} u_x' = \frac{u_x}{\sqrt{u_x^2 + u_y^2}} \\
u_y' = \frac{n_y}{\sqrt{u_x^2 + u_y^2}} \end{cases}$$

Comment: I'm seeing persistent rendering errors, which vanish when editing. If anyone notices rendering issues in the formulae, let me know in a comment.

Comment: My guess is it's because you're reusing labels you used in your other answer.  The entire page renders as one $\LaTeX$ document, not as separate documents for each answer.  Notice how your tag links in your 2D answer go to the labels in your 3D answer.

Comment: @tilper: That makes sense. After adjusting the labels, it renders now correctly. Thanks!